# Java Compile Error, Can't find the reason

Tags: java

My Teacher gave me this question to solve.

Design a ComplexNumber class.

a.  Take a ComplexNumber from user.

b.  Implement increaseValue() to increase both real & imaginary part by 2.

c.  Print the ComplexNumber from main method using toString.

So, I wrote a class that will take a string input i.e a complex number like "5+i6".
In return it will give "7+i8"

I tried the code my it's showing error again and again. 
Please help me out where is the fault & if you have a better way to solve this please share.

```
public class ComplexNumber{

    int real, imagine; //(When I declare the integers before it shows compile error too)
    public static String complex;

    public static void doit(String str){
        complex=str;
    }

    String []splt = complex.split("\\+");
    real=Integer.parseInt(splt[0])+2; //This line shows error

    splt[1]=splt[1].replaceAll("^[0-9]","");    
    imagine=Integer.parseInt(splt[1])+2;//This line shows error

    public String toString(){ //This line shows error
        return (real+"+"+"i"+imagine);
    }
} //This 2nd bracket is showing error :/
```

Comment: remove the closing } after `complex=str;` , becaus it ends the block for the `doit` method and the next lines have to be within the method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to execute code outside of any method context, starting with your line:

```
String []splt = complex.split("\\+");
```

In Java all code has to be in a method. You may wonder how anything gets executed in that case. There is a special method called `main` that is used as the entry point to a class. See for example the [hello world program here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/) which illustrates the basic structure of a Java program.

**As a side note, your assignment seems to be targeted at teaching you the basics of Object-oriented programming, but your solution isn't very object oriented. A suggestion to point you in the right direction is to think of a ComplexNumber as a *thing*. It can be constructed with a string like `"3+4i"`. This becomes a part of the state of the number. Then you can do things to that number, using a method, like `myNumber.increaseIt()`. Your job is probably to figure out how to construct a ComplexNumber from the string and implement `increaseIt()`.

Comment: I solved the problem. I included the code in the method now I can compile but it's not giving the correct output. 

Example If I pass a String "5+i6" after calling toString it should return "7+i8"

but it's not

Comment: Well, there isn't any place where you actually increase the value in the real or imaginary numbers. You need some place to increase it. I would recommend changing your method `doit(String str)` to a constructor for the ComplexNumber class (`ComplexNumber(String str)`), and then give the ComplexNumber class a method `public void increaseValue()` which will add one to `real` and `imagine` and re-store them. Then if someone constructs an instance with a string, calls `increaseValue()`, and calls `toString()` on the result, they will get what you want.

Comment: I would recommend talking to your teacher or a helpful classmate about what object state means, what methods are, and how they can be usefully applied. If you just want reading on the subject, check out the basics of [what an object is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have some statements that are outside a method or constructor. You cannot have statements at class level, outside a method or constructor.

Put those statements inside a method or constructor.

See these sections of Oracle's Java Tutorials:

- [Defining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)
- [Providing Constructors for Your Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)
- [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)